React native error virtualizedLists Should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews
i have error  React native error virtualizedLists Should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation because it can break windowing and other  functionaliy
and this my code :

return(
 
  <ScrollView> 
      <View Style={styles.container}> 
      <View style={{width:'100%',padding:20,backgroundColor:"#eeeeee",}}> 
         <View>
            <Image style={styles.imageThumnail} source={require('../assets/coba.jpg')} />
           <Text  style={{ lineHeight:24, fontWeight:'600', width:'90%',color: '#fff', bottom: 20, alignSelf: 'center', fontSize:18, position: 'absolute',}}>SuperCel Rilis Trailer Squad Buster Bertabur Bintang</Text>
         </View>
      </View>


      <View style={{backgroundColor:'#fff',padding:5}}> 
      <View style={styles.containerBoxArtikel}>
      <Text style={{color: 'black',marginTop:15,marginBottom:5,fontSize:18, fontWeight:'900'}}>Terkini</Text> 
        {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          vertical={false}
          keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={styles.boxArtikel}>
               <View style={{flexDirection: 'column',width:'40%',height:140,backgroundColor:'#fff'}}>
                 <Image style={styles.imageArtikelLeft} source={{uri:  item.cover }} />
               </View>
               <View style={{flexDirection: 'column', width:'56%',height:150,backgroundColor:'#fff',paddingLeft:12}}>
                  <Text  style={{ lineHeight:24,color: 'black',fontSize:16, fontWeight:'600'}}> {item.title}</Text>
                </View>
             </View>
          )}
        />
      )} 
     </View>
     </View>   


     </View>
      </ScrollView> 
 
      
)
}

can somebody help me how the solutions for this error

Does this answer your question? ERROR - VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation

This has been asked many a time, and I think the one of the better threads that explains the many ways to solve this issue to be found here. You're particular example would be the prop ListHeaderComponent and ListFooterComponent found in FlatList. Here's your code with a few added changes for readability:
const HeaderComponent = () => (
  <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
    <Image style={styles.imageThumbnail} source={require('../assets/coba.jpg')} />
    <Text style={styles.headerText}>
      SuperCel Rilis Trailer Squad Buster Bertabur Bintang
    </Text>
  </View>
);

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList
      data={isLoading ? [] : data}
      ListHeaderComponent={HeaderComponent}
      keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View style={styles.boxArtikel}>
          <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
            <Image style={styles.imageArtikelLeft} source={{ uri: item.cover }} />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.textContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.itemTitle}>{item.title}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      )}
      ListEmptyComponent={() => isLoading && <ActivityIndicator />}
    />
  </View>
);


